# Throw error when the unlicensed user access the Lightning custom record page with the record detail and custom components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, profile, userlicense

I created a **managed** package with a custom **lightning component**. After I installed this package in another org, I created a custom record page for Account object. I dragged the record detail component and the custom component into the custom page and activated it. It worked fine with the licensed user. But if a user is not licensed and the profile is **System Administrator**, it will throw an error which is "Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, bet in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. ErrorID: 14292951943210(-1328812164)". But if the unlicensed user with any other profiles except System Administrator, then it is also worked.

I guess the error is because of the license, but don't know how can I catch this exception and don't know why only System Administrator did not work. Can anyone just explain how this license check works in lightning? Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but Salesforce have finally admitted that this is a bug (after fighting with the clowns in support).

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=noaccessexception-on-getting-apextype-for-an-auraenabled-method-containing-inaccessible-sobject-in-the-signature&Id=a1p3A000000Fmqh